# MSpaint won't open in Run console(win+r), while it opens well in CMD console

Tags: windows-11, security-policy

I run(win+r) `mspaint` frequently and it became a habit that I don't want to change.
After Windows update some days ago, running `mspaint` resulted in permission error.
I cannot revert Windows update since it's not my PC.

History:

$$ means I tried to run mspaint with RUN console

1. $$-> failed with permission error
2. Changed C:\Program Files\WindowsApps security owner from TrustedInstaller to Administrators
3. Erased the Microsoft Store Cache(WSReset.exe)
4. $$-> failed with library error
5. Erased my SID from
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\
6. Erased my SID(unknown user) from security property of
   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Paint_11.2206.6.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
   My window user is still in the administrator group.
7. $$ -> Nothing happens. Doesn't run the app but returns no error.
8. Restored the Paint app from Control. $$-> Does not work.
9. Removed the Paint app and re-installed. $$-> Does not work, except that mspaint opens from CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my Windows 10 computer.

After such extensive hacking of Windows as you did, it's pretty hard
to predict or analyze anything.

To return Windows to a known state, I suggest doing
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: What's the difference between running mspaint in `cmd` and in `run` console?

Comment: There should not be much of a difference, except perhaps in the starting directory, if you have ever modified it in the registry.

Comment: Repair-installed Windows 11. C:\Program Files\WindowsApps authorities are restored bakc to normal, but mspaint still won't open with run.